# Return with NULL if ID does not match in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have three tables that I need to join together.

1- `payments` table:

```
id
member_id
year_id
notes
paid
paid_at
created_at
updated_at
```

2- `yearly_fees` table:

```
id
year
amount
created_at
updated_at
```

3- `members` table:

```
id
first_name
last_name
```

What I am trying to do is show a list of all of the members who paid and did not pay in xxxx year.

Expected example output:

```
id  first_name  father_name     notes       paid    year    amount
1   test name   test last_name  test note   1       2018    3000
2   test name   test last_name  test note   NULL    NULL    NULL
3   test name   test last_name  test note   1       2018    3000
4   test name   test last_name  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
5   test name   test last_name  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

This is the query that I wrote:

```
SELECT `members`.`id`, `members`.`first_name`, `members`.`last_name`, 
`payments`.`notes`, `payments`.`paid`, `yearly_fees`.`year`, 
`yearly_fees`.`amount` FROM `members` 
LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.member_id = members.id 
LEFT JOIN yearly_fees ON yearly_fees.id = payments.year_id
WHERE payments.year_id = 4
```

Result:

```
id  first_name  father_name     notes       paid    year    amount
1   test name   test last_name  test note   1       2018    3000
2   test name   test last_name  test note   1       2018    3000
3   test name   test last_name  test note   1       2018    3000
```

The `WHERE` statement is only outputting the rows that match with the `payments` table but what I want is for it to also output every member even if the rest of rows result to NULL. If I remove the `WHERE` statement, it works exactly the way I want it but it's getting me all of years and not the one I specifically want.

This is an example output:

```
id  first_name  father_name     notes       paid    year    amount
1   test name   test last_name  test note   1       2016    3000
2   test name   test last_name  test note   1       2015    3000
3   test name   test last_name  test note   1       2018    3000
4   test name   test last_name  test note   1       2018    3000
5   test name   test last_name  test note   1       2018    3000
6   test name   test last_name  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
7   test name   test last_name  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Apologies in advance for the bad English.

Comment: why not add `OR payments.year_id=NULL` ?

Comment: @Demonyowh you can't compare to `NULL` you need to check for it with `IS NULL` i.e. `OR payments.year_id IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the conditions to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT `m`.`id`, `m`.`first_name`, `m`.`last_name`, 
       `p`.`notes`, `p`.`paid`, `yf`.`year`, `yf`.`amount`
FROM `members` m JOIN
     yearly_fees yf
     ON yf.year_id = 4 LEFT JOIN
     payments p
     ON p.member_id = m.id AND p.year_id = yf.id;
```

If makes more sense to `JOIN` `yearly_fees` first, because that match should always be there.  Then use `LEFT JOIN` to see if there is a matching row in `payments`.

Comment: yearly_fees does not have year_id. table payments does

Comment: @rabin . . . Whatever the join is between the tables.

Comment: instead of `yf.year_id` use `yf.id`